# How can i send request with SyncHttpClient from fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is my code to request to server..

```
    final SyncHttpClient client = new SyncHttpClient();

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("product[name]", name);
    params.put("product[price]", price);

    client.post(context,Config.URL_GET_ALL_PRODUCT, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {

            super.onStart();
            setUseSynchronousMode(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            String result = new String(responseBody);
            try {
                JSONObject eventResult = new JSONObject(result);

                String id = eventResult.getString("id");
                // Check for error node in json
                if (id != null || id != "" ) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "New Product Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = eventResult.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            System.out.println(error.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my code to call the method in Fragment

```
 ProductController.addProduct(getContext().getApplicationContext(), nameProduct, priceProduct);
```

Error for this code

Unhandled exception origin cause
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 at com.project.roy.interview.Control.ProductController.addProduct(ProductController.java:102)
at com.project.roy.interview.Fragment.FragmentAddProduct$1.onClick(FragmentAddProduct.java:38

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of this library its written:

> Processes http requests in synchronous mode, so your caller thread
>   will be blocked on each request

On Android you may not block the main thread, thats where your Exception comes from.

Either use an AsyncTask, or execute this code inside a separate thread.

Comment: How can i execute this code inside a separate thread?